# ggplot , legend does not shift to bottom

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to place the legend at bottom in a single row.

```
guides(fill= guide_legend(nrow = 1))  

theme_set(theme_bw() + theme(legend.position = 'bottom', legend.direction = "horizontal"))
```

I tried the guides and theme but the legend does not shift to bottom.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps try calling `theme` outside of `theme_set`.

Instead of:

```
theme_set(theme_bw() + theme(legend.position = 'bottom', legend.direction = "horizontal"))
```

Try:

```
theme_set(theme_bw()) +
theme(legend.position = 'bottom', legend.direction = "horizontal")
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked! But, I used library lemon. And it worked. Is it possible to change the order of legend? And also add 2 more colors to legend that are not related to plot ?

Comment: Order of factors: https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/7433_4537ea5073dc4162950abb715f513469.html. I think you will have more luck posting different questions as separate answers.